# $T$ is diagonalizable on finite dimensional v.s. $\implies$ $(T^2+T+I)(\vec v) \ne \vec 0 , \forall \vec v \ne \vec0$?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a diagonalizable (over $\mathbb R$) operator on a finite dimensional real vector space  ; then is it true that there is no non-zero vector $\vec v$  such that $(T^2+T+I)(\vec v)=\vec 0$ ? (where $I$ is the identity map )

Comment: Do you mean diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Travis: Diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes true. Notice that if $\lambda$ is an  eigenvalue for $T$ then for every polynomial $P$, $P(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $P(T)$ hence if $v\ne0$ exists such that $(T^2+T+I)v=0$ then there's $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $T$ such that

$$\lambda^2+\lambda+1=0$$
which is a contradiction since in this case $\lambda\not\in\Bbb R$.